# How to set ASP.NET control property through IIf statement

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I am not sure if things have changed after .NET 2.0 because in .NET 2.0 I used to be able to set something like this:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%#IIf(Some condition here, "true", "false") %>' />
```

I did this all the time to have a clean code behind.

Currently I am working with .NET 3.0 and I cannot for the life of me get this working. The condition which i am evaluating is not accessing any data binding fields but is as simple as checking the property of an object in the code behind.
  Can anyone suggest how this inline-code should look?

### UPDATE:

Here is an example of what i am trying to do. I swear something like this used to work in .NET 2.0 but it does not work now:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0               Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server">
        protected bool IsValid() { return true; }       
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label Text="123" runat="server" Visible=<%#iif(IsValid(), "true", "false")%>/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your `IIF`. If you'd target 3.5 you could use [IF-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which uses short-circuit evaluation instead.

Comment: Perhaps show some more code to make your question a little clearer.

Comment: What is telling you that it is not working?

Comment: @Bala: Do you know an `IIF` in C#?

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP hasn't mentioned vb/c#. Maybe he used to use vb.net and now he's using c# and hence it's not working?

Comment: Have you tried changing <%# to <%= ?  <%# is for data binding

Comment: <%= doesn't work inside property values. It will literally render the expression including the <%= %>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VB in markup and C# in codebehind

```
<%@ Page Language="VB"
```

Sure.. Visual Studio goes crazy

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm6.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm6" %>

<asp:repeater id="rpt" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <br />
            <%# Container.DataItem %>
            <br />
            <%#IIf( CType(Container.DataItem, System.Int32) > 5 = 0, "true", "false") %>
            <br />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:repeater>
```

and C# in code behind

```
using System.Linq;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm6 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            rpt.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 29);
            rpt.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

And what VS feels about it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<%#` indicates that you databind the control/page. So either you do

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.DataBind()
End Sub
```

or you do it in codebehind completely(what i prefer):

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MyPanel.Visble = YourCondition
End Sub
```

http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, for me personally I like to put things like hiding/showing of controls in the .ASPX to make the code behind more clear. I posted simple example of what I am trying to do as an update to the original post.

Comment: @user1171461: the opposite is true. The aspx is the visual frontend responsible only for layout. The codebehind is for business logic.